# Search bar in Angular 6+ to search API

Tags: angular, api

I created a search bar in Angular, I'm using the sidebar nav component.  I want the search box to be in the top header and then the results to show on a result component which will then be a separate page.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
   <img src="{{ logo }}" alt="Logo">
   <span class="menuLabel">Menu</span>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <ul>
      <li class="nav-item"><a mat-list-item class="nav-link" routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a mat-list-item class="nav-link" routerLink="resources" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fas fa-archive"></i> Resources</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a mat-list-item class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar>
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><app-search></app-search></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><app-user></app-user></div>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <ng-content>
    </ng-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The search component:

```
<div class="results">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input  matInput placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchInput" name="search">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button (click)="onSearch(searchInput)" type="button"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

This will get results if they are on the same component but I can't figure out how to get them to a different component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  query: any;

  searchInput: '';
  searchReturned = false;

  handleSuccess(data) {
    this.query = data.results;
    this.searchReturned = true;

  }

  constructor( private searchService: FetchDataService ) {}



  ngOnInit() {
  }


  onSearch(query: string) {
    return this.searchService.getSearch(query).subscribe(
      data => this.handleSuccess(data),
      error => console.log(error),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You ... pass the results to the other component? did you try that? Or have the other component subscribe to the observable emitted by the FetchDataService.

Comment: I tried having the results component subscribe to the FetchDataService but it doesn't take the search bar input, it will just pulls the search results without a search term which is basically every file on the API

Comment: Well yes, if you redo the search. But when you "do" a search (eg call `getSearch`) you get back a promise of some kind. That exact instance is what your other components should be subscribed on. The search bar itself probably doesn't care what the search results are so it has little reason to subscribe itself.

Comment: Not sure if it is the most efficient way but I got it to work by saving the input value to the service and then calling that from the results component and inserting that value into the search function

Comment: I mean theres plenty of ways. You could register the search bar as a viewchild of some containing component, or even use an event emitter and have the results view component register a listener on the search action, or a service to share data between components. I probably would have done some variant on the event emitter myself.